# How can I uncheck the options from multiple selected select pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to uncheck the selected options from the select picker based on the  values passed into a function.
To achieve this I'm using the below code. I'm using the `onclick` event to uncheck the options a,b...

```
$("#select1 option[value='"+myname+"']").prop("selected", false);
```

```js
function rem(myname) {
  $("#select1 option[value='" + myname + "']").prop("selected", false);

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="container body-content">
  Select Fee Types
  <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="select1" name="select1" data-width="200px" data-size="4" data-live-search="true" multiple>
<option disabled>Select</option>
<option value="a,b" selected>a</option>
<option value="d,c" selected>c</option>
<option value="f,e">e</option>
 </select>
</div>

<button onclick=r em( 'a,b')>Unselect</button>
```

Comment: What about `$('#select1').val($("#select1 option[value='" + myname + "').val())` ?

Comment: Just FYI I added the answer you were asking for :)

Comment: @Tech If you used my answer than please accept it, that is how SO works. I will apprciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your function

**$("#select1").selectpicker("refresh");** is missing in your function which is proper way to update selectpicker

```
function rem(myname) {

  $("#select1 option[value='"+myname+"']").prop("selected", false);

  $("#select1").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

```js
function rem(myname) {

  $("#select1 option[value='"+myname+"']").prop("selected", false);

  $("#select1").selectpicker("refresh");
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="container body-content">
  Select Fee Types
<select class="selectpicker form-control" id="select1" name="select1" data-width="200px" data-size="4" data-live-search="true"  multiple>
<option disabled>Select</option>
<option value="a,b" selected>a</option>
<option value="d,c" selected>c</option>
<option value="f,e">e</option>
 </select>
  </div>
  
  <button onclick = rem('a,b')>Unselect</button>
```

Comment: Nope, won't cut it

Comment: thanks for the reply......i just want to uncheck only one option passed as an  argument in the javscript function rem()

Comment: Hi , Tech I could not understand Question Properly. check @nikamanish  has already added solution as required

Comment: Yeah, he coppied my solution wich wasn't really efiicient. But lower is my new solution that works :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you have two options. If you want only to deselect specific values you can do it as shown in snippet. If you want to deselect all values you can simply do it like this: `$("#select1").selectpicker('deselectAll');` ([source](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerdeselectall))

How did I find the answer? I typed "bootstrap-select methods" in google browser and it was first result. Please before you ask a question do some research by your own :) If you did, then no problem ;)

```js
function rem(myname) {
  $("#select1 option[value='" + myname + "']").prop("selected", false);
  $("#select1").selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<div class="container body-content">
  Select Fee Types
  <select class="selectpicker form-control" id="select1" name="select1" data-width="200px" data-size="4" data-live-search="true" multiple>
<option disabled>Select</option>
<option value="a,b" selected>a</option>
<option value="d,c" selected>c</option>
<option value="f,e">e</option>
 </select>
</div>

<button onclick="rem('a,b')">Unselect</button>
```